# facebook getlogin url not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to let user login via facebook. I'm using this code:

```
  <?php

    require 'include/facebook.php';
    require 'include/fbconfig.php';
    require 'include/user.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => APP_ID,
                'secret' => APP_SECRET,
                'cookie' => true
            ));

    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    if (!empty($session)) {
        # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
        try {
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $user = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }

        if (!empty($user)) {
            # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($user);
            echo '</pre><br/>';
            $username = $user['name'];
            $user = new User();
// check user method insert login information to my database and return the result
            $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username);
            if(!empty($userdata)){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
                $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
                $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
                header("Location: test.php");
            }
        } else {
            # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
            die("There was an error.");
        }
    } else {
        # There's no active session, let's generate one
        $params = array(
         'scope' => 'email'
      );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        header("Location: " . $login_url);
    }
    ?>
```

The problem when I run this page, it redirects me to the facebook home page(to my account ).

Please, any ideas ??
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: I wasn't logged in into my facebook account. it redirect me to facebook login. After I login, it shows error message:
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Please migrate to OAuth2 and use new /dialog/oauth endpoint. return_session is no longer available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the newest PHP SDK? Get the latest SDK from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk), and then try again..

**[EDITED]**

Replace all references to `getSession()` with  `getUser()`

Example:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

it should say:

```
$session = $facebook->getUser();
```

ref: [Upgrade to PHP SDK v3.0.0](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503)

Comment: I downloaded the new sdk. but another error show which is :

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession()

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried alot of things, but I didn't realised that I was using the old version of the sdk. @ Sahil

Answer (score 2):

This would work surely -

```
$user=NULL ;
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
if($user)
{
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
       array(
              'scope'         => 'email',
              'redirect_uri'  => 'https://appurl'
            )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged in you're not going to se the login-page.

Try logging out and check if your code works.

Comment: facebook dialog (asking me about permission) didn't show to me